# exp_online_users table corrupt after PHP upgrade

Tags: database-error

We have a server with several sites running various version of Expression Engine.  We upgraded PHP last night and after the upgrade 2 sites has the table exp_online_users corrupt.  I ran a repair command on the tables and the number of rows was reduced by 2 in each database and then the site ran fine.  These 2 sites run older versions of Expression Engine.

Ideas of what could have caused the table to be corrupt?

Comment: If you have the 2 table versions you could do a text comparison and see if anything stands out?

Comment: I did not make a backup of the database before I ran the repair.  I am thinking the there was some writing going on in the database when apache was restarted and when that happened not all of the database writes had a chance to complete.

Comment: It shouldn't have been as a result of Apache being restarted, unless the database server was also restarted? In any case, that happens on occasion with MySQL, seems like it may be coincidence that it was the same table on two separate databases, though. That table doesn't hold any critical information and can be repaired and truncated as needed, too; it's just for site stats.